# How to split a complex string in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

Given the following string:

```
my_string = "fan_num=2,fan1=0,fan2=0,chain_xtime8={X0=8,X1=3,X2=11},chain_offside_6=0,chain_offside_7=0,chain_offside_8=0,chain_opencore_6=0,chain_opencore_7=0,chain_opencore_8=0"
```

How can I split it such that I get the following output:

```
[ 
  fan_num=2,
  fan1=0,
  fan2=0,
  chain_xtime8={X0=8,X1=3,X2=11},
  chain_offside_6=0,
  chain_offside_7=0,
  chain_offside_8=0,
  chain_opencore_6=0,
  chain_opencore_7=0,
  chain_opencore_8=0
]
```

I've tried:

```
output = my_string.split(',')
```

However, that splits the `chain_xtime8` value which is not what I want. I am using Python 2.7.

Comment: Is this a standard, named format? There might be an existing parser.

Comment: It's not a standard as far as I am aware.

Comment: Here's a regex that seems to work correctly - you could iterate through the matches/groups: https://regex101.com/r/zn2f2o/1 (click "Code Generator" on the left for python example code)

Comment: So you don't want to split if comma is within brackets?

Answer (score 2):

Through a series of convoluted replacements, I converted this style into JSON. Then using `json.loads` you can convert it into a Python dict. This ASSUMES you do not use the characters being replaced and you continue only using integers as values

This can obviously be tightened up but I wanted to leave it readable

```
import json

my_string = "fan_num=2,fan1=0,fan2=0,chain_xtime8={X0=8,X1=3,X2=11},chain_offside_6=0,chain_offside_7=0,chain_offside_8=0,chain_opencore_6=0,chain_opencore_7=0,chain_opencore_8=0"

my_string = '{"' + my_string + '"}'
my_string = my_string.replace('=', '":"')
my_string = my_string.replace(',', '","')
my_string = my_string.replace('"{', '{"')
my_string = my_string.replace('}"', '"}')
myDict = json.loads(my_string)
```

`pprint` of `myDict` results :

```
{'chain_offside_6': '0',
 'chain_offside_7': '0',
 'chain_offside_8': '0',
 'chain_opencore_6': '0',
 'chain_opencore_7': '0',
 'chain_opencore_8': '0',
 'chain_xtime8': {'X0': '8', 'X1': '3', 'X2': '11'},
 'fan1': '0',
 'fan2': '0',
 'fan_num': '2'}
```

Also one more example -

```
print(myDict['chain_xtime8']['X0'])
>> 8
```

Comment: This will corrupt data if it contains strings with those special characters. Though, I don't think his dataset has it, do it shouldn't matter

Comment: Yes I should've explicitly mentioned that. This is assuming they continue to only use integers as their values